# Does a bounded function converge if its derivative tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have function $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$ that is bounded $|f(t)|<M$ and differentiable such that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f'(t) = 0$. Does this imply that $f(t)$ converges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea: If you drop the boundedness assumption, $\ln(x)$ does provide a counterexample to what you want.

Now think about how you can transform this counterexample into a bounded counterexample.

Hint

> Typical bounded functions include $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Ive spent way too long thinking about that...

Comment: Sorry for being a bit pedantic, but you'll need $\ln(x+c)$ for some $c>0$ to get a counterexample. $\ln$ itself is not bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}_+$. (The bounded counterexample I came up with using your hint is neat, though!)

Answer (score 2):

In general the answer is NOT. Let's consider the function $f(t) = \sin(\ln(t))$. Its derivative $f' = \cos(\ln(t))/t$ converges to $0$ but in limit, the function keeps oscillating.