# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$ implies $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists finite?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> If $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x>0$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0,$$ 
>   then
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$ 
>   exists finite.

Is that statement right or wrong?

Comment: There is a famous function whose derivative is $\frac 1 x$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Yeah but I want to know if this statment always correct?

Comment: What is the anti-derivative of the example and its limit?

Comment: what you mean by anti derivative?

Comment: Dont you think you could edit the title of the question to make it more precise? If people are looking for an answer this is really generic. And there are a couple of typos also...And now that i see your profile you have several question like that. It is only a suggestion

Comment: It is a question from college to prove if this statement is right or wrong always,I posted the same question here

Comment: @sam0101 nicomezi is trying to show you a counter-example. The existence of a single counter-example should tell you enought to judge on the validity of your statement.

Comment: The converse i.e. if $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ is finite, then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) =0$ is correct, given that f(x) is everywhere differentiable on $\mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: @LordKK No it is not.

Comment: @nicomezi  I think it can be proved easily using  mean value theorem. Can you give counter-example, if it not true. I may be wrong.

Comment: @nicomezi thanks, I get it now, which is lan(x)

Comment: @LordKK An everywhere differentiable counterexample is hard to write analitycally but it exists. Consider $f'$ made of smooth bumps functions centered at every integer being tighter as $x \to \infty$ with equal heights. If those bumps tighten fast enough, $f$ will have a finite limit while $f'$ does not have any limit.

Comment: @nicomezi  I am assuming that limit of f(x) at $\infty$ does exist. Then using mean value theorem, one can show that limit of $f'(x)$ at $\infty$ is $0$. Only one thing could have devoided this possibility, when  f'(x) itself would have been discontinuous, but here since limit of f'(x) exist, it is at least defined at $\infty$

Comment: If you assume it exists, then yes it is correct. But your comment was not very clear on that point. @LordKK

Comment: @LordKK: A simple counterexample is $f(x)=\sin(x^2)/x$.

Comment: @sam0101: It's not even true if you drop the word “finite” (i.e., allow $f'(x)$ to have the improper limit $+\infty$ or $-\infty$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131369/does-a-bounded-function-converge-if-its-derivative-tends-to-zero

Comment: @HansLundmark  Thanks. So, given $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =L$  there can be two possibilities. Either $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)$ doesn't exist, but if it exists, it will necessarily be equal to **zero**. I am confused whether this function in your example can be called differentiable on $\mathbb{R^+}$. Can we consider function differentiable, if its derivative exists everywhere, but not defined at $\infty$

Comment: @LordKK: Yes, certainly. $\infty$ is not an element of the set $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your limits are strange. You might like to write
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0\text{ and }\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L.
$$

Next, we are not doing your homework. You should try it yourself.

The first try should be $f'(x)=x^{-n}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Obviously, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0$. How about $f$?

*(Be carefull to check $n=1$ and $n>2$ as different cases)*

Comment: Believe me, if I could solve this question, I would post a harder question that I couldn't solve.

Comment: I wrote what you should try. If you do so, you will see something which leads you to the answer.